# `reduce(add,...)` vs `sum(...)`, why the second fails on a list of objects

Tags: python, sum, reduce

I have the expectation that `reduce(add,lst)` and `sum(lst)` should give me the same result, but

```
In [18]: class p():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x ; self.y=y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%r,%r)"%(self.x,self.y)
    def __add__(self, P):
        return p(self.x+P.x, self.y+P.y)
   ....:     
In [19]: pts=[p(1,0), p(2,1), p(-3,4)]
In [20]: from operator import add
In [21]: print reduce(add,pts)
(0,5)
In [22]: print sum(pts)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-98a81789d257> in <module>()
----> 1 print sum(pts)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'instance'
In [23]:
```

of course I'm not understanding something, possibly obvious; could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`reduce()` starts with `pts[0]` as the initial value (unless you give it an explicit starting value), but `sum()` defaults with `0`. From the [`sum()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>   Sums *start* and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. *start* defaults to `0`.

Give `sum()` a better *start* value; use the first object just like `reduce()` does:

```
sum(pts[1:], pts[0])
```

or a suitable empty value:

```
sum(pts, p(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define `__radd__` to special case if 0 is added to an instance of your object, then you can just use `sum()`.

```
    ... rest of Point class defn ...
def __radd__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return self
    raise TypeError("invalid type to add to point")

print sum(pts)
```

will give `(0,5)`.